# Android, Drawables stay in memory until explicitly nullified

Tags: android, android-layout, android-memory

When in an Activity I create a layout programmatically (without layout.xml at all) and assign a drawable for it from pool of drawables, then destroy said Activity, memory doesn't get GC'd unless I do

```
layout.getBackground.setCallback(null);
layout.setBackground(null);
```

Where could I look up an explanation on why does this happen and why is there difference between layout.xml and programmatically created layout? In first case, I don't have to call setBackground(null) for some reason.

Update: code below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    //Setting up UI
    layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(Stuff.getRandomDrawable(ManageCities.this));
    cityUpdater = new Button(context);
    cityRemover = new Button(context);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.pls_wait);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    cityUpdater.setText(R.string.update_city_list);
    cityRemover.setText(R.string.remove_city);
    cityRemover.setOnClickListener(this);
    cityUpdater.setOnClickListener(this);
    database = WalkerDatabase.getInstance(
            getSharedPreferences(FirstActivity.getPrefsName(), 0).
                    getString("datapath", null));
    adapter = database.getItems();
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ur = new WifiUpdateReciever(cityUpdater);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(ur, intentFilter);
    if (adapter.isEmpty()) {
        cityRemover.setEnabled(false);
    }
    layout.addView(cityUpdater);
    layout.addView(cityRemover);
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (!Stuff.isRunningOnEmulator()) {
        if (!mWifi.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.wifi_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            cityUpdater.setEnabled(false);
            cityUpdater.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: replace: `Context context = getApplicationContext();` with `Context context = this;`

Comment: pskink, thank you. Reading up on context.

Answer (score 0):

UI related things which are related to activity you should always use activity context.

Here also

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

is wrong practice. You should use

```
Context context = this;
```

here